# How to get PHP to echo other php file's contents?

Tags: php

I want php to echo all of a .php's file contents, even php code. How can I do that.

For example:

```
<?php
echo "Code";
?>
```

I want PHP to output a PHP file even though it contains PHP code, as if it were a text file with php code.

Comment: Em, PHP file may not contain PHP code?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

```
readfile('/path/to/file.php');
```

If it doesn't look the way you want becuase of code / HTML then either surround with `<pre></pre>` tags or use:

```
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.php'));
```

Comment: All that did was echo a number :/

Comment: Because you used echo (I didn't) :-)

Comment: probably because you're dumping to a browser, and the `<?php ... ?>` tags will be treated as unknown/illegal html tags. try `<pre><?php readfile(...) ?></pre>`

Comment: add htmlspecialchars and nl2br :)

Comment: I want it to be displayed to the user. Why won't it work with echo ? <pre> didn't help either

Comment: Look it up. `readfile` echoes it already but returns an int, so you are echoing the number of bytes read from the file.

Comment: Ok. thank you the second code you posted worked with the htmlentities.